# Hyperledger Fabric Channel creation from client VM fails due to authentication failer on Orderer VM

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to execute the Hyperledger Fabric with the configuration and steps provide in the link below :

https://blockchain-fabric.blogspot.in/2017/09/underconstruction-setting-up-blockchain.html

But not able to create create Channels on Orderer using the step 8.

On the client VM i am getting the following error:

"Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST"

On the orderer VM i am getting the following message:

"Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org0"))"

As i have already passed the relative path for crypto-config, i am not able to figure out why authentication fails.

Any guidance on the same please.

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path instead? The local fabric-ca-server will -at some point- convert its paths to absolute ones. Also try using cryptogen again in order to regenerate your local certificates.

Comment: @CXgamer i have regenerate all local certificates but still the same issue. Can you please guide me where and how to pass the absolute path? As right now i am passing the path where generated certificated are stored but it is not working.